# What do we call a person who is obsessed with cleanliness?

Tags: synonyms

Is there any word for a person who is very , very much concerned about cleanliness and keeping things hygienic and even point out faults in clean things and explaining that they were dirty ?

Comment: No, there's no single-word substitute in general English for that.

Comment: We call them *a person obsessed with cleanliness*.  What do you call them?

Comment: They might be a germaphobe or mysophobe also.

Answer (score 4):

I would probably call that person a [neat freak](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=neat%20freak).  They also might have obsessive compulsive disorder.

Comment: That's not listed on standard dictionaries, though. It's **informal AmE**.

Comment: @Kris - that's where dictionaries lack then.  The phrase has been around for 30 years at least and anyone in the US would understand it.

Comment: +1: That or "clean freak" would do.

Comment: @Robusto *clean freak* lost out to *neat freak* early on. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=neat+freak%2Cclean+freak&year_start=1950

Comment: @Kris: It didn't "lose out" at all. You are making a specious argument from a limited data set. English isn't a winner-take-all horse race, for Pete's sake. Words aren't "disqualified" in some sense because they are used less than other words.

Comment: @Robusto - I think clean freak is good here too.  But I think it has a slight connotation of someone obsessed about their own cleanliness vs. environment.

Answer (score 1):

In pathological terms an **ablutomaniac**.

Comment: This is what you would say if you didn't care whether people could understand what you were talking about.

Comment: -1 What does the word mean? What is the source of the information? Why would the word be suitable for the OP's context? Without these supporting facts, it cannot be considered an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could say a number of things: *anal retentive* or just *anal*, *neat freak*, *OCD* referring to *obsessive compulsive disorder*, or "*stickler* for x"

*Anal* can describe someone who is clean to the point of it becoming a problem, however it is commonly used it in an exaggerating sense.

*Neat freak* is just as another poster mentioned, but it is an AmE colloquialism.

*OCD* is similar to anal in the sense that people are obsessed about keeping things neat, or in whatever way they think things should be.

*Stickler* is a word you might not see very commonly but if you mention it to a native English speaker they should get your gist.

I'll give some examples:

> Take your shoes off, man. My wife is really **anal** about making sure nobody wears shoes in the house.
>   Alternatively: My mom was always **anal retentive** when I was growing up; if she didn't know where I was at all times she would call me and have me give a status report.
>
> He's such a **neat freak**, every time I drop a few chips while eating the guy whips out his handheld vacuum and cleans them up.
>
> I'm *so* **OCD** about my cups that I order them from shortest to tallest in the cupboard.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider the word [fastidious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fastidious), though it refers more to one's meticulous nature than cleanliness directly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a [mysophobe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mysophobia) a.k.a. a germaphobe.